# MVC Sitemap Provider Persist Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, mvcsitemapprovider

This has been driving me crazy for the last couple of hours. I am using the MVC Sitemap Provider to add breadcrumb functionality.

Let me go through the steps of what I have done so I can make this as clear as possible

- Downloaded the resource from Nuget
- I then have the following in my sitemap

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  ```

  ```
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Vehicles" controller="Vehicles" area="Vehicles" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="VehicleName" controller="Vehicles" area="Vehicles" action="Showroom" >
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Overview" area="Vehicles" controller="Vehicles" action="Overview" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
  ```
- And I have this in my view

  @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
- My first questions is: How can I have in replace "VehicleName" for action Showroom, with my actual VehicleName?
- My actual problem is: My id is not persisted through to the parent. For example my url will be  localhost:44357/Vehicles/Overview/Soul/1, and the parent url will be  localhost:44357/Vehicles/Showroom, instead of localhost:44357/Vehicles/Showroom/Soul/1. The vehiclename in the url is optional, so the url can just be localhost:44357/Vehicles/Showroom/1.

I hope this makes sense

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For questions 1: Set the VehicleName on the parent node. For example: ((MvcSiteMapNode)SiteMap.CurrentNode.Parent).RouteValues.Add("VehicleName", "SomeVehicle");. A good option may also be to use dynamic node providers for creating your sitemap structure.

For question 2: [SiteMapPreserveRouteData] should do the trick